# Vert.x - Event bus closes in IE

Tags: groovy, vert.x

Running a Vert.x server (Vert.x 1.3.0) in Groovy and deploy our module and the web module, running on port 9099 (not used by anything else I have running). In Firefox and Chrome, the event bus appears to stay open forever, but in IE, the event bus closes after a few seconds, and I get this:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:225)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:193)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:359)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:59)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:471)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Other users of this vert.x server have not had this problem. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: 1.3.0 -- added to the original post; thanks!

Comment: 1.3.1 was released monday, can you check with that? I remember lots of IE things mentioned on the mailing list (not sure if this was one of them though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in 1.3.1.

I recommend you use the google group for questions since I don't scan stackoverflow very often.